# Profile picture from cloud storage to database - Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I would like to save a profile picture of a user in my database and to use it later.

I saved it to my firebase cloud storage with this code :

```
    private void uploadImage() {

    if(picture != null)
    {
        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setTitle("Uploading...");
        progressDialog.show();

        StorageReference ref = storageReference.child("images"+ UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        ref.putFile(picture)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();

                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed "+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                })
                .addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        double progress = (100.0*taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()/taskSnapshot
                                .getTotalByteCount());
                        progressDialog.setMessage("Uploaded "+(int)progress+"%");
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

Now, I want to save it as a child in my Database...
I have this code to save all the datas (Name, email, phone, password...)

```
mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(edtEmail.getText().toString(), edtPassword.getText().toString())
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(AuthResult authResult) {
                            User user = new User();
                            user.setEmail(edtEmail.getText().toString());
                            user.setPhone(edtPhone.getText().toString());
                            user.setPassword(edtPassword.getText().toString());
                            user.setName(edtName.getText().toString());
                            user.setId(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
                            user.setProfilePic(picture);
```

But the "user.setProfilePic(picture)" doesn't work...

What could be the best way to save the profile picture of the user on my database ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats not the right way of doing it. What you should do is,

**1)** Store images in storage it self, with some UUID.

**2)** Store that reference of image in the storage.

**3)** Get the data from `database` use libraries like [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) or [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) to load the images to avoid `OutOfMemory` Exception.

Here is the example

```
 StorageReference ref = storageReference.child("images"+ UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    ref.putFile(picture)
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
               Uri downloadUri = taskSnapshot.getMetadata().getDownloadUrl();
               String downloadurl = mDownloadUrl.toString();

                }
            })

           );
```

And now

```
  User user = new User();
  user.setEmail(edtEmail.getText().toString());
  user.setPhone(edtPhone.getText().toString());
  user.setPassword(edtPassword.getText().toString());
  user.setName(edtName.getText().toString());
  user.setId(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
  user.setProfilePic(downloadurl);  //here picture URL
```

And final Step just to push the data to `DataBase`

```
String key = mDatabase.child("YourNodeHere").push().getKey();
mDatabase.child("YourNodeHere").child(key).setValue(user);
```

Comment: it worked, now I have a new child on my database for ex : "        profilePic : "7a5f406f-6bf2-4159-b451-33a02f666ce9". now I added it to show it with Picasso :     Picasso.with(getBaseContext()).load(storageReference.getPath()).into(ivProfilePic);   , There is No error but I don't see the picture on my ImageView, do you know why ?

Comment: thats because thats not the complete url of the picture, let me share it with you

Comment: So what is the complete Url of the picture on that case ?

Comment: @DavidOUIZEMAN please check the edited answer , although you will have to make little bit changes according to your code , but it will clear all the things

Comment: Thank you ! I try with this : " downloadurl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl().toString();

                            String key = users.child("profilePic").push().getKey();
                            downloadurl = MainActivity.users.child(key).toString(); ",                                      Now I get the complete Url on my database but I can't see it with Picasso , I wrote it : "                 Picasso.with(getBaseContext()).load(MainActivity.downloadurl).into(ivProfilePic); " Can you help me ?

Comment: just to test simply , use that url in browser and check if it shows in the browser

Comment: when I put it in the browser, it shows the adress of the user in my database and ":null"       : "-LADT1_0TesgFwCoVmKy : null
" for example

Comment: @DavidOUIZEMAN thats not the url of the picture, its the url of the database i think, I need url of the picture

Comment: But my picture is saved into cloud storage, and that's what i get when I write " downloadurl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl().toString(); "

Comment: try this `taskSnapshot.getMetadata().getDownloadUrl().toString();`

Comment: I got the same result with "taskSnapshot.getMetadata().getDownloadUrl().toString();" ... I got exactly the same Url and It does not show me the picture

Comment: where did you put `taskSnapshot.getMetadata().getDownloadUrl().toString();` this ?

Comment: on the onSuccess of my function " uploadImage()"

Comment: public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                            progressDialog.dismiss();

                          downloadurl = taskSnapshot.getMetadata().getDownloadUrl().toString();

                            String key = users.child("profilePic").push().getKey();
                            downloadurl = MainActivity.users.child(key).toString();

                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

Answer (score 0):

To save the profile picture in the database try this:

```
         ref=db.child(mCurrentUser.getUid());
         StorageReference filepath=mStorage.child(uri.getLastPathSegment()); 
          filepath.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() { 
             @Override
           public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) { 
           String downloadurl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl().toString(); 
           ref.child("image").setValue(downloadurl);
           //can save other data also

            }
      });
```

First add the url of the image in the firebase storage, then if added successfully, you will be able to retrieve the url `String downloadurl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl().toString();` and add it to the database `child("image").setValue(downloadurl);`

more info here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files